# How to Show Next and Previous buttons of same category?

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a site https://kidzgeek.com/, I wanna show Next and previous buttons at the bottom of the page under the same category, but I was facing problem in showing the same category in it, it's showing in according to the published dates.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
the_posts_pagination( array(
            'mid_size'  => 2,
            'prev_text' => '<span class="fa fa-angle-double-left"></span>',
            'next_text' => '<span class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></span>',
        ) );
```